# How to apply three more color in RDLC report field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

i have try but not effect in report so please help me...
i have Following textfield like this below
MO
CL
AB
P

i used this in font expression to change color

```
=IIf((Fields!TotalHrs.Value ="O") , "Blue" ,
IIf(( Fields!TotalHrs.Value ="AB" ), "Red" ,"DarkGreen"))
```

it works but not able to add other two fields MO and P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all four values are from the same field then you can do it by using below code.

```
=IIf(Fields!TotalHrs.Value ="O", "Blue" ,
IIf(Fields!TotalHrs.Value ="AB", "Red" ,
IIf(Fields!TotalHrs.Value ="MO","Green",
IIf(Fields!TotalHrs.Value ="P","Yellow","White"))))
```

Let me know if anything is not working.